# When an UPDATE/DELETE transaction acquires lock on a row when a huge number of rows are to be updated

Tags: postgresql, database-deadlocks

Let us say that I have a DELETE/UPDATE statement that is supposed to update/delete 100million rows.
Then will the DELETE/UPDATE statement acquire lock on the entire 100million rows right at the beginning of the transaction or will it acquire lock as it encounters rows while updating their values?

Simulating this scenario has proven to be very tough for me. Any help would really be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

I can't tell for sure if it's true for all RDBMS or not, but for Postgres, MS SQL Server and Oracle following is true:

Before it starts updating anything, DBMS tries to acquire lock on every row, only after it gets the lock on every row it needs, then it starts updating/deleting.

Also interesting note, let's say you need to update rows with id 1,2 and 3.
Let's say 2 is locked, your update will still locks row 1 and 3 and it will wait for row 2 to lock it as well, until than it will hold the lock on row 1 and  3 and only when it gets the lock on row 2 as well and update all 3 rows - only than it releases the lock.

Hope this info will help you in some way.